# Issue with embedding pre-trained model in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a pre-trained Fasttext model and I want to embed it in Keras.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(MAX_NB_WORDS, 
                    EMBEDDING_DIM, 
                    input_length=X.shape[1],
                    input_length=4,
                    weights=[embedding_matrix],
                    trainable=False))
```

But it didn't work.

I found that lots of people have same problems with embedding pre-trained model to Keras, and all of them are left with no solution.

It seems like `weights` and `embeddings_initializer` are deprecated.

Is there any alternative method to solve the problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean with "didn't work"?

Comment: TypeError: add() got an unexpected keyword argument 'weights'. It seems like 'weights' are deprecated. So 'didn't work' means the pre-trained model can't be embedded in Keras by this method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Weights parameter is deprecated in Embedding layer of Keras.

The new version of embedding layer will look like below -

```
embedding_layer = Embedding(num_words,
                            EMBEDDING_DIM,
                            embeddings_initializer=Constant(embedding_matrix),
                            input_length=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,
                            trainable=False)
```

You can find latest version of embedding layer details here - [Keras Embedding Layer](https://keras.io/layers/embeddings/)

You can find the example of pretrained word embedding here - [Pretrained Word Embedding](https://keras.io/examples/pretrained_word_embeddings/)

Comment: @james_24 - If I have answered your question, can you please accept and upvote it. Thank You.

Comment: @james_24 - If you are satisfied with answer, can you please mark the answer as accepted. Kindly click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.